# How can I take out some parts of the String?

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String value like this.

"Apple:1#Banana:2#Cake:3#Dog:4#Elephant:5"

a word : a number # a word : a number ...

and I want to separate the Strings into:

```
Apple

1

Banana

2

Cake

3

Dog

4

Elephant

5

...
```

However, I do not know how long the String is. Is there any way I can split each content connected with ":" and "#"?

Comment: You can pass a regular expression into the `split` method, such as `[#:]`.

Comment: Can this be told that what will the last thing in the string be? Like whether it will be a number, or a word, or `:` ot `#`?

Answer (score 1):

Split on `:` or `#`:

```
String[] parts = str.split("[:#]");
```

Comment: Finally, someone's listening to me!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your input: ");

        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        Arrays.stream(input.split("[:#]")).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This is the code that gets input for example `Apple:1#Banana:2#Cake:3#Dog:4#Elephant:5` and it will split the input by `#` and `:` and print them line by line.

The result shown on the console will be like

```
Enter your input: 
Apple:1#Banana:2#Cake:3#Dog:4#Elephant:5
Apple
1
Banana
2
Cake
3
Dog
4
Elephant
5
```

Or you can do with a simpler way without streams

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your input: ");

        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length();) {
            int nextHashIdx = input.indexOf("#", i);
            if (nextHashIdx == -1) nextHashIdx = input.length();

            String strWithColon = input.substring(i, nextHashIdx);
            String[] strs = strWithColon.split(":");
            System.out.println(strs[0]);
            System.out.println(strs[1]);

            i = nextHashIdx + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, you have truly nuked the mosquito!  This is far more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Yeah .. I need to make this into some more simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all `:` symbol to `#` and split the string by `#`.

```
String str = "Apple:1#Banana:2#Cake:3#Dog:4#Elephant:5#";
       String strrep = str.replaceAll(":","#");
        String splitted[] = strrep.split("#");
        for (String i : splitted){
           System.out.println(i);
        }
```

Comment: Why would you do that when you can just split by `[#:]`, as per my earlier comment?

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice way to do this. But, it helps op if he isn't interested to use regex

Comment: Whenever you call `split`, you're using a regular expression.